# FormData is empty in parent when passed from child component

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, form-data

Beginner Alert! :) I am setting FormData in child component and then passing it to the parent component using formReducer and dispatch, but in parent formData.entries() is always empty!

ChildComponent.js

```
function ChildComponent({signed, fileAttached}){
    const { dispatch } = useContext(ContactFormContext);

     const changeHandler = (event) => {

const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('File', event.target.files[0]);


dispatch({ type: "FILE_ATTACHED", payload: formData })
};

return (
<>
            <div>
        <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
    </div>
</>);
}
```

ParentComponent.js

```
function useFormProgress(fileAttached) {
     
     
    function goForward() {
        const currentStep = 1;

        let appvariables = [
                {
                  "key": "PUID",
                  "value": "a2sd"
                },
                {
                  "key": "ApplicationNames",
                  "value": "Trello, abc"
                }
              ];
        switch(currentStep) {
          case 0:
            break;
          case 1:
            console.log(fileAttached);
          if(fileAttached != null)
              sendEmail("Resignation Letter", appvariables, fileAttached);
          break;
        }
    }
    return [goForward];
}

function sendEmail(templateName, variables, attachment){
  console.log("sending email...");
    const requestBody = {
                    "templateName": templateName,
                    "recipients": [    
                    "abc@xyz.com"
                    ],
                    "variables":  variables,
                    "files": attachment
                };

fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Email',{
  method:'Post',
  body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
 });

}

const initialState = {
      signed: "",
      fileAttached: null
};

function formReducer(state, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGNED":
      return { ...state, signed: action.payload };
    case "FILE_ATTACHED":
      return {...state, fileAttached: action.payload};
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}


function ParentComponent() {

   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, initialState);
     const { signed, fileAttached } = state;

     const steps = [<ChildComponent {...{signed, fileAttached}}/>];

   const [goForward] = useFormProgress(fileAttached);


    return (
        <ContactFormContext.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
          <div>{steps[0]}
        <div><button onClick={e => {
           e.preventDefault();
              goForward();
        }}
             
        >  Parent Button
        </button>
        </div>
    </div>
        </ContactFormContext.Provider>
       );
}
```

ContactFormContext.js

```
const ContactFormContext = React.createContext();
```

In the switch statement above (ParentComponent), the console.log(FileAttached) shows FormData with 0 entries(see image attached), also the API request is not successful.!

[image]

you can try it out in https://jscomplete.com/playground

1. add context on top
2. add child component code
3. add parentcomponent code
4. add the following line

   ```
     ReactDOM.render(<ParentComponent/>, mountNode);
   ```

**MyAPI Method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Get(EmailRequest email)
    {
         //the request never comes here
     }
```

EmailRequest.cs

```
public class EmailRequest
{
    public string TemplateName { get; set; }
    public string[] Recipients { get; set; }
    public List<Variables> Variables { get; set; }
    public FormFileCollection files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In the ParentComponent where you render ChildComponent in ContactFormContext.Provider as child?

Comment: sorry about that let me add it

Comment: Could you share with us ContactFormContext as well please?

Comment: Send context file content to simulate them by me  into  codesandbox

Comment: added context file content its really a declaration - try the jsplayground steps to immitate it - I am also adding my api method signature in c#

Comment: Still do you have any problem?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get values from entries method of FormData by using console.log you should do it like this:

```
  for (var [key, value] of attachment.entries()) {
    console.log("log from for loop", key, value);
  }
```

also, if you want to send file to server using POST request, you cannot stringify file that you want to send. What you are sending currently in your json payload looks like this `"files": {}`. You need to serialize it in a different manner. This means that you need to change the way you are sending this file.
Check the answers of this question:
[How do I upload a file with the JS fetch API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api)

For serializing FormData, you can can check this post: https://gomakethings.com/serializing-form-data-with-the-vanilla-js-formdata-object/

Answer (score 0):

I added your codes in codesandbox and everything seems to be ok.

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cherry-ymhee?file=/src/ParentComponent.jsx)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, starting from Lazar Nikolic's answer above  to stop trying json.stringify!.. after stumbling onto a few blockers here and there I am finally able to send a File successfully to the API!!

Here are some important steps to note:

In the backend - I changed controller method:

1. Added [FromForm] tag

   ```
   [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Get([FromForm] EmailRequest email)
   ```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58938944/upload-files-with-additional-information-angular-8-to-c-sharp-core-3) helped me.

In the Front-end side

1. Changed ChildComponent.js as follows

   ```
   function ChildComponent({signed, fileAttached}){
   const { dispatch } = useContext(ContactFormContext);

   const changeHandler = (event) => {

   dispatch({ type: "FILE_ATTACHED", payload: event.target.files[0] })
   };

   return (
   <>
        <div>
    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={changeHandler} />
   </div>
   </>);
   }
   ```
2. Changed sendEmail function in ParentComponent.js as follows

   ```
   function sendEmail(templateName, variables, attachment){
     console.log("sending email...");

     const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('files', attachment);
    formData.append('templateName', templateName);
    formData.append('recipients', [    
     "abc@xyz.com"
    ]);
    formData.append('variables', variables);


   fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/Email',{
   method:'Post',
   body: formData,
   //headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
   });

   }
   ```
3. Notice the email object being received as a result had all properties set as null until I removed the Content-type header and then the browser will add multipart/form-data header itself.. I got this help from @madhu131313's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067767/how-do-i-upload-a-file-with-the-js-fetch-api)
4. we cannot pass an object array directly under form-data so variables array was empty..i did the following

   ```
   for(let i = 0; i < variables.length; i++){
    formData.append(`variables[` + i + `].key`, variables[i].key);
    formData.append(`variables[` + i + `].value`, variables[i].value);
   }
   ```

instead of

```
   formData.append('variables', variables);
```

and changed recipients as follows:

```
   let recipients = [    
  "abc@xyz.com",
  "nop@xyz.com",
  "stu@xyz.com"
  ];

   for(let i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++){
    formData.append(`recipients[` + i + `]`, recipients[i]);
  }
```